Локальные приложения Битрикс24 на Next.js на локальном компьютере
С наступающим Вас, друзья.
Подскажите пожалуйста, как писать локальные приложения для Битрикс (допустим, мне нужно написать собственную форму автозаполнения организации по ИНН) с помощью Next.js на Вебшторме

Вот, допустим, я сделал привязку к серверу запускаемому на Next.js
Делаю самую простую Helloword страницу. В браузере на локалхосте всё отрабатывает, в Битриксе не пашет, как я понял из-за того, что запрос передаётся POST-ом.
Оговорюсь - я только обучаюсь )
Next.js я настроил с использованием папки app, а не page

Вопросы - нужно ли мне будет использовать layout или достаточно page.js?
Как правильно начать этот page.js, чтобы он обрабатывал пост (я не совсем ещё понял, там будет только разметка или пост-запрос он всё-таки примет?)
Или необходимо пропускать его через middleware?
Если сможете пример рабочего Helloword'а, то желательно в js ,а не в тайпскрипте )
ПыСы: по-итогу это должна получиться форма, которая ищет в checko.ru организацию по ИНН и получает json с информацией. Как всё это сделать и далее раскидать по полям в Битриксе буду разбираться далее.) Сейчас бы, вообще стартануть, чтобы можно было изменять и улучшать код в Вебшторме.
Спасибо )
PPS: начинал я пробовать по этому ролику - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VEV4Y8AuNv0
Но, при npm install, валится множество ошибок, ибо ролику три года и пакеты React'а уже безнадёжно устарели.
Как я понял, там он запускает сервер, чтобы отрабатывался POST, но не во всех скриптах разобрался.
Пытался поставить React через CRA, но там тоже какие-то ошибки попёрли и многие советуют переходить на другие фреймворки, в их числе - Next.
Поскольку хотел немного поразбираться с этим фреймворком, то за него и взялся, но пока в нём, как среди трёх сосен )
И вот тут не совсем сообразил, каким макаром мне правильно портировать файлы из ролика в Next.js, чтобы начать хоть немного разбираться как это работает. Но, пока получается только лазить по интернетам в попытках найти ответы, почему вообще нифига не работает )
